# Why can't dot files in root directory be moved

Tags: bash, mv

There're some files, folders and dot files in a directory like following

```
|-folder1
|----folder2
|----file.json
|----file2.php
|----.env
|----.dockerfile
|----.someconfig
|----.dockerignore
```

I run command `mv $(ls | egrep -v '(.dockerfile|.env)') ../new_directory` to move all files in directory `folder1` to the `new_directory` exclude `.dockerfile` and `.env`, but actually all dot files can't be moved, why?

Comment: You're missing the `ls` flag to show files that start with a `.`

Comment: as above and also… you'll still of course get dot files that won't be moved . and .. ;-)

Comment: [The mandatory "do not parse `ls`" link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thank you @cutrightjm

Answer (score 3):

If you run

```
ls | egrep -v '(.dockerfile|.env)'
```

on its own, you’ll get an idea of what’s happening here: the output will be

```
file2.php
file.json
folder2
```

This happens because `ls` doesn’t list dotfiles by default. To include dotfiles, but not `.` or `..`, use `ls -A`:

```
$ ls -A | egrep -v '(.dockerfile|.env)'
.dockerignore
file2.php
file.json
folder2
.someconfig
```

You don’t need to use `ls` here (and [you shouldn’t](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440)), you can use Bash’s extended [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob
mv !(.dockerfile|.env|.|..) ../new_directory
```

This will match all files *not* named `.dockerfile`, `.env`, `.` or `..`. Using this approach, you won’t have any issues with file names containing spaces, newlines etc.

`shopt -s extglob` enabled extended pattern matching, and `shopt -s dotglob` allows globs to match dot files.

Comment: Thank you, I run `mv !(.dockerfile|.env|.|..) ../new_directory`, but I got the error `no matches found: !(.dockerfile|.env|.|..)`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that `extglob` needs to be enabled, see the update.

Comment: I'd expect `!(.dockerfile|.env|.|..)` expansion not to include hidden files unless you set the `dotglob` option though IIRC it was different in older versions of `bash`. What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: Looks like it went back and forth, 4.2 didn't include dotfiles, 4.3 and 4.4 did, 5.0 don't any longer again. All include `.` and `..` with dotglob (unless excluded manually like you do here) which I'd consider a bug.

Comment: Sorry, not *all*. 4.2 and 3.2 didn't include `.` and `..` with dotglob and `!(.foo)` for instance! bash-5.2 has a globskipdots option to always exclude them like pdksh / zsh / fish do.

Comment: I tested this on bash 4.4.20, with `extglob` on and `dotglob` off.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `ls` for this.  Parsing the output of `ls` is unreliable at best, dangerous at worst.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Try `find` instead.  e.g. with GNU `find` (and GNU `cp`):

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -regextype awk \
  ! -regex './(|\.env|\.dockerfile)' \
  -exec echo cp -t ../new_directory/ {} +
```

I use `-regextype awk` because I'm very used to the regular expression dialect in awk and I don't want to waste time figuring out the exact dialect used in `find-default`.  `-regextype egrep` would have worked just as well.  You can get a list of dialects available by running `find -regextype help` (unfortunately, PCRE isn't one of them).

The `-regex ...` excludes `./`, `./env`, and `./dockerfile`.  Note that neither `^` nor `$` anchors are required, they're implicit with `find`'s `-regex` predicate, so you only get exact matches.  If you want partial matches, you have to add `.*` to the beginning and/or end of your regular expression.  This is why I had to include the `./` in the regex.

If I were to run this from the parent, directory, it would have to be written as:

```
find folder1/ -maxdepth 1 -regextype awk \
  ! -regex 'folder1/(|\.env|\.dockerfile)' \
  -exec echo cp -t ../newfolder {} +
```

or with some other pattern that matched the path, e.g. `'.*/(|\.env|\.dockerfile)'`.

The `echo` makes this a dry-run, to show you what would be copied without actually copying them.  Remove it when you've confirmed the command will do what you want.

GNU `cp`'s `-t` option allows you to specify the target directory before the list of files to be copied.